Performance Issues with Filtering by Relationship in Laravel Query (whereHas with Status)
I’m working on optimizing a query in Laravel, but I’m running into performance issues on the server (though it works fine locally). The query filters a Person model by the status of its latest visit using a relationship with the VisitData model. Specifically, I’m filtering based on the visit_status_id field, which comes from the opt_visit_statuses table (where the status IDs are 1, 2, 3, and 4).
Relevant Models:
Person Model
The Person model has a lastVisit relationship, which fetches the latest visit for the person:
public function lastVisit()
{ 
    return $this->hasOne(VisitData::class)->latest('visit_date');
}

VisitData Model
The VisitData model stores information about visits, including the visit_status_id:
class VisitData extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'visit_id', 
        'person_id', 
        'visit_status_id', 
        'refuse_reason_id',
        'comment', 
        'visit_date'
    ];

    public function visit(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Visit::class);
    }

    public function person(){
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'id', 'person_id');
    }

    public function visitStatus(){
        return $this->hasOne(VisitStatus::class, 'id', 'visit_status_id');
    }
}

**Current Query
**
In the index method of my controller, I’m filtering persons based on several criteria, including the visit_status_id of the latest visit:
$persons = Person::with('vulnerabilityGroup', 'gender', 'documentType', 'citizenship', 'family', 'lastVisit.visit', 'lastVisit.visitStatus')
    ->withCount('documents', 'verifiedMember')
**    ->when($visitStatus, function ($query) use ($visitStatus) {
        return $query->whereHas('lastVisit', function ($q) use ($visitStatus) {
            $q->where('visit_status_id', $visitStatus);
        });
    })**
    ->paginate(30);

Issue
•Performance: This query works fine on my local environment but is slow when running on the server.
•Filtering by Status: $visitStatus comes from the opt_visit_statuses table and represents the id field. There are four possible IDs (1, 2, 3, 4). I’m concerned that this filtering might be causing the slowdown.

**Question:
**
What else can I do to improve the performance of this query on the server? Is there anything wrong with the way I’m filtering by visit_status_id using whereHas? Could the way I’m handling the relationship be optimized further?
Additional Info
•.I’m using Laravel 8.
•.The database engine is MySQL.
•.The visit_status_id is indexed, and I’ve confirmed the IDs (1, 2, 3, 4) exist and are correct.

Any advice on optimizing this query would be greatly appreciated!
Steps I’ve Taken

Indexing: I added an index on the visit_status_id column in the visit_data table.
Optimized Relationship: I adjusted the lastVisit method to use the latest('visit_date') instead of ofMany() to ensure I’m getting the latest visit.
3.Checked for NULL values: I checked that the visit_status_id field does not have unexpected NULL values.
4.Eager Loading: I’m eager loading the lastVisit relationship to reduce the number of queries.

